# How to format dates for fiscal year in SQL View in phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, date, phpmyadmin

I have the following code in phpMYAdmin but the logic is not pulling the dates I need.  This is a view, not a table.

> `` select `kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`evdet_id` AS `evdet_id`,date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtstart`),'%m-%d-%Y') AS `FROM_UNIXTIME(dtstart, '%m-%d-%Y')`,date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtend`),'%m-%d-%Y') AS `FROM_UNIXTIME(dtend,'%m-%d-%Y-%H')`,date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtstart`),'%H') AS `FROM_UNIXTIME(dtstart,'%H')`,date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtend`),'%H') AS `FROM_UNIXTIME(dtend,'%H')`,`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`summary` AS `summary`,`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`description` AS `description` from `kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail` where (date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtstart`),('%Y-%m-%d' >= '2014-07-01')) and date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtstart`),('%Y-%m-%d' <= '2015-06-30'))) ``

Comment: you need to clean that up so it's readable. There's so much formatting going on, the logic itself is basically invisible.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the feedback.  I am new to SQL statements and using views.  Can you offer incite on how to clean up the code?  I thought it had to be formated this way to display correctly on the website.

Comment: rip out pretty much ALL of that date_format business, unless it's actually being used as part of your logic. you don't need to put in the table name on all the fields - only those where the field name would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally incorrect:

```
(date_format(from_unixtime(`kyfirewi_sfrt714`.`qxv_jevents_vevdetail`.`dtstart`),('%Y-%m-%d' >= '2014-07-01'))
```

If you strip it down:

```
date_format(from_unixtime(dtstart),('format' > 'date'))
```

You're not passing in a format string to `date_format`, you're passing in the boolean result of a `>` comparison of two strings. That makes no sense whatsoever.

Plus, even if this were written correctly, it would be HIGHLY inefficient. You're taking a unixtimestamp (a signed 32bit int), converting it to a date/time value, and then comparing it to another date/time literal. That means indexes cannot be used - the results of functions cannot be indexed. You'd better off doing:

```
dtstart >= unix_timestamp('2014-07-01 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you SSSOOOO much.  I stripped it down and got rid of the garbage then I could see the mistake.  I used the unix_timestamp and checked it against my dates and it worked.  I really appreciate your help.